# Are the Sins in dreams, sins?

Tags: five-precepts, dreams

**Background**: Recently when I was in the deep sleep I saw some dreams, which showed that I am going against the five precepts. 
For Instance, I lied somebody. I felt that as I lie in real life; I remember that I planned about revealing disinformation and creatively managed the flow of false information.
If it was a real situation I may not act in such way.

Is this scenario really cause to break the fourth precept?
As we know, dreams are born based on the feelings of our subconscious mind. Therefore, Isn't it my own fault to see such a dream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than in situation you are in [deep sleep (bhavanga)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhavanga) you create Kamma. Since when you are dreaming you are still creating karma as you cannot dream in deep sleep. These are not very strong or deep kamma and in most cases may not give any results and if they do they will be very mild (maybe like an itch which we might experience then the result comes). They do not have potent to create a new rebirth. For this to happen it should be backed by action or word giving desired result. More particularly:

- The statement must be untrue.
- There must be an intention to deceive.
- An effort must be made to deceive.
- The other person must know the meaning of what is expressed.

Kamma creation to a dream is based on reaction you can react:

- pleasant dream you react with craving
- unpleasant dream you can react with aversion
- neutral dream you are still deluded

These reaction can lead to mental kamma.

In many cases as these kamma has very little potent, it can be ignored held there is no kamma created due to dreaming like in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/14922/295).

Additional references that might be of interest:

- [The Unconscious](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/17.8b-The-unconscious.-piya.pdf) an essay by Piya Tan
- [Unconscious Views](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/31.9-Unconscious-views.-piya.pdf) an essay by Piya Tan
- [Anusaya](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/31.3-Anusaya.-piya.pdf) an essay by Piya Tan
- [Vinnana](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/17.8a-Khandha-5-Vinnana-piya.pdf) an essay by Piya Tan
- [Vedana](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/17.3-Khandha-2-Vedana-piya.pdf) an essay by Piya Tan

Answer (score 2):

According to Buddhism, to do a sin, you have to consciously do something using your body, speech or using sitha.

In a dream you are not doing anything consciously. Therefore simply you can not sin in dreams.